# how to connect a handleSubmit to another page with condition in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

when the user fills the sing up form and clicks the sing up button   it has to be two scenarios

first: if the password and confirm password is matching it has to route to  the dashboard page

second: if the password and confirm password is not matching it has to alert a massage ("Passwords do not match")

mine I used condition at Log.jsx  down below for a function called handlesubmit , in that condition the first part of the condition is not working but the second part of the condition that regarding the second scenario is working and alerting the massage

here is my code and some screenshots

Log.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "./log.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Log() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    passwordConfirm: "",
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (formData.password === formData.passwordConfirm) {
      return (
        <Link className="link" to={"/Dashboard"}>
        </Link>
      );
    } else {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
      return;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="loginn">
      <div className="login-items">
        <div className="title-log">
          <p className="login-title">sing up</p>
        </div>

        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <span className="fullname">Fullname</span>
          <input
            className="input-lg"
            type="name"
            placeholder="Email address"
            name="fullName"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={formData.fullName}
          ></input>
          <span className="email">Email</span>
          <input
            className="input-lg"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={formData.email}
          ></input>
          <span className="password">Password</span>
          <input
            className="input-lg"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={formData.password}
          ></input>
          <span className="password">Confirm Password</span>
          <input
            className="input-lg"
            type="password"
            name="passwordConfirm"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={formData.passwordConfirm}
          ></input>
          <button className="login-btn">Sing up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import Naav from '../../components/naav/Naav'
import Log from '../../components/log/Log'
import Footer from '../../components/footer/Footer'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='home'>
    <Naav/>
    <Log/>
    <Footer/>


    </div>
  )
}
```

Dashboard.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "./dashboard.css"
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Navtwo from "../../components/navtwo/Navtwo";
import Cards from "../../components/cards/Cards";
import Data from "../../components/data/Data";
import Title from "../../components/title/Title";

export default function Dashboard() {
  return( <div className="dashboard">
      <Sidebar/>
      <Navtwo/>
      <Title/>
      <Cards/>
      <Data/>
  </div>
  )
}
```

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import "./app.css";
import Headerr from "./components/headerr/Headerr";
import Naav from "./components/naav/Naav";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";
import Log from "./components/log/Log";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Navtwo from "./components/navtwo/Navtwo";
import Cards from "./components/cards/Cards";
import Title from "./components/title/Title";
import Data from "./components/data/Data";
import Dashboard from "./pages/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const currentUser = false;
  return (

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/Dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>   );
}
```

[image: screenview of the app]

Comment: "I want to link..." This looks like you are asking several things in a very long sentence. Break this down to individual requirements. You should word these from the point of view of the user. For example, "When the user goes to the sign up form, fills it out, and clicks on the "sign up" button, then..." Fill in what happens after the user takes this action. Write out each scenario separately as a complete sentence. Thinking in this way will help you figure out what your app is supposed to do before trying to write any code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleSubmit` function, you return the `Link` component.
That does nothing!

There are 2 ways you can go about here.

1. Create a state `passwordMatch`, and set it inside `handleSubmit`. If the passwords do not match, return the `Redirect` element instead of the form.
2. Import the `history` and call it to navigate where you want inside the `handleSubmit`